# Scroll to selected tablecell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uipickerview, tablecell

I implemented a TableView to show up a PickerView when a particular row is selected. But that would sometime block the selected cell. So, I want my scrollView to scroll to the selected cell when the pickerView shows up.

Is there anyway to get the current location of the selected row? Such that I can implement something like

```
//---scroll to the current text field---
CGRect textFieldRect = [currentTextField frame];
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];
```

Thanks.

Comment: so are you using a scrollView ?

Comment: Yes, I am. The scrolView needs to scroll up when PickView is shown.

Comment: Have you looked at the convertPoint:fromView: method? It will give you the point where the cell is in your tableView, and from there, you can move the scrollView to that point you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve the pickerView or the keyboard hiding the screen, you can try this approach. Implement the `heightForFooterInSection` and set a height value, and the tableView will scroll up to the same value as you specify there.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 70.0;
}
```

If you just want the tableView to scroll , just implement the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`

**Edit:**

Since you are using a `UIScrollView`, you can programmatically scroll to a certain region using

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

Also read through this reference: http://www.aaron.griffith.name/weblog/2011/02/23/scrolling-a-uiscrollview-programmatically/

Comment: No, I am not trying to scroll the tableview. I am trying to scroll my scrollView up to the selected row. Something like                //---scroll to the current text field---
    CGRect textFieldRect = [currentTextField frame];
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

Comment: in your question you tell clearly that you want to scull the TableViewCell. Does that not mean the tableView ?